# NGINX does not seem to redirect correctly and gives me a 404 error

Tags: centos, nginx, webserver

I have a mern application where the front-end seems to be working fine while the back-end does not work at all.

The back-end should work on 127.0.0.1:3000/api but given the following error message it always redirects to 127.0.0.1:3000:

```
2018/07/25 15:32:43 [error] 31172#0: *4 open() "/var/www/Interface-2.0/Client/dist/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 130.63.1.192, server: edafos.eng.yorku.ca, request: "POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/register", host: "edafos.eng.yorku.ca", referrer: "https://edafos.eng.yorku.ca/register"
```

I have tried a few things such as adding /api into the upstream and proxy_pass.
I have also commented the rewrite in location ^~ /api block. Everything was unsuccessful and I always get the same error in the logs.

Here's my full config file:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
    upstream app_edafos {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    #Point http requests to https
    server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name edafos.eng.yorku.ca;
        server_tokens off;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name edafos.eng.yorku.ca;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.ca/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.ca/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;

        root /var/www/Interface-2.0/Client/dist;     
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            error_page 405 = $uri;
        }

        location ^~ /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*)$ /$1 break;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Ssl on;

            proxy_pass https://app_edafos;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this issue?
Also, the requested URL looks like this https://edafos.eng.yorku.ca/api/auth/register